# Plotting continues field's properties by having some points information

Tags: plotting, interpolation, vector

Having information of a vector field in some discrete points in 2D space(points and vectors are both in 2D), how can one plots (approximate) divergence of the vector-field in the total space(not in discrete points)? Is there any function in Mathematica which take information of vector field in some discrete points and do that? Any example provided answer is highly appreciated.

I have found this useful link through searching which is relevant:
[Discrete vector_field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435896/discretizing-a-formula-for-simulation)

Trying first answer:

```
field[{x_, y_}] := {Sin[x y], Cos[x + y]};
        randomPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
        discreteField = randomPoints /. p_List?(Length[#] == 2 &) :> {p, field[p]};

        Graphics[discreteField /. {pt_List, v_List} :> Arrow[{pt, pt + 0.2 v}]]
VxInt = Interpolation[
   discreteField /. {pt_List, {vx_, vy_}} :> {pt, vx}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
VyInt = Interpolation[
   discreteField /. {pt_List, {vx_, vy_}} :> {pt, vy}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];

VectorPlot[{VxInt[x, y], VyInt[x, y]}, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]

curl[x_, y_] = -Derivative[0, 1][VxInt][x, y] + 
  Derivative[1, 0][VyInt][x, y]

DensityPlot[
 curl[x, y] - Curl[field[{x, y}], {x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 
  2}, {y, -1, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

As it is clear from the first and the second picture, there is a rotation in point (1.5 ,0). But the last output doesn't show a high value of the curl at this point.

Comment: It's unwise to calculate curl at point (1.5, 0) when interpolation was done on points in region [−1,1]×[−1,1]. `InterpolationFunction` is not `ExtrapolationFunction`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an interpolation on the (un)structured grid.

Suppose you have a vector field in discrete points:

```
field[{x_, y_}] := {Sin[x y], Cos[x + y]};
        randomPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
        discreteField = randomPoints /. p_List?(Length[#] == 2 &) :> {p, field[p]};

        Graphics[discreteField /. {pt_List, v_List} :> Arrow[{pt, pt + 0.2 v}]]
```

[image]

You interpolate each component separately:

```
VxInt = Interpolation[discreteField /. {pt_List, {vx_, vy_}} :> {pt, vx}, 
            InterpolationOrder -> All];
        VyInt = Interpolation[discreteField /. {pt_List, {vx_, vy_}} :> {pt, vy}, 
            InterpolationOrder -> All];

        VectorPlot[{VxInt[x, y], VyInt[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Then you can treat it like a continuous function. For example, you can calculate the divergence and compare to the divergence of the initial field.

```
DensityPlot[
            Div[{VxInt[x, y], VyInt[x, y]}, {x, y}] - Div[field[{x, y}], {x, y}]
            // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: What are white wholes in final graph?

Comment: When I change your final code to the below, It plots nothing!: DensityPlot[
 Curl[{VxInt[x, y], VyInt[x, y]}, {x, y}] - 
   Curl[field[{x, y}], {x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Comment: White regions show where values are out of range, try `PlotRange->All` to see all values.

Unfortunately, `Curl` works strangely with `InterpolatingFunction`. Try `curl[x_, y_] = -Derivative[0,1][VxInt][x,y]+Derivative[1,0][VyInt][x,y]` and then `DensityPlot[curl[x,y]-Curl[field[{x,y}], {x, y}]//Evaluate,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]`

Comment: I think there is a problem in the curl. Please see my edit to the question